# Stored procedure with optional parameters not showing null values for joined table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, left-join, optional-parameters

I've looked around and found various approaches to this problem, but none that worked in my specific situation. I wrote a stored procedure which I'm using for an SSRS report which accommodates for optional parameters (in SSRS, I'm specifying a list of available parameters, along with an "All" option where the value is set to "=Nothing"). This works for accommodating for multiple optional parameters when, if nothing is selected, all records are shown... except for those with null ProjectID values.

I'd like to be able to run the stored procedure and specify "Null" for the @Project parameter and be shown those values with null ProjectID fields, and ideally, add a "None" option to my SSRS report for this parameter, which would also show those values.

I'm not quite sure how to modify the SP to achieve this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TasksByStatus]

@Status AS Integer = NULL,
@Project AS Integer = NULL

AS

BEGIN

SELECT Task, CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 101) AS StartDate, 
      (CASE WHEN CompleteDate IS NULL THEN 'Not complete yet' 
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CompleteDate, 101) END) AS CompleteDate, 
      (CASE WHEN Notes IS NULL THEN 'No notes provided' ELSE Notes END) AS Notes, 
       ProjectName, StatusName
FROM Tasks 
INNER JOIN Status ON Tasks.StatusID = Status.ID
LEFT JOIN Projects ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID 
AND Projects.ID IS NULL

WHERE Status.ID = ISNULL(@Status, Status.ID) 
AND Projects.ID = ISNULL(@Project, Projects.ID)
ORDER BY StartDate, StatusName

END
```

Results of query without specifying parameters:

[image: Results of query without specifying parameters]

I intent, when specifying NULL for @Project to see only that one record with a NULL ProjectID value.

**Edit to further clarify**

To OP, please let us know what the exact results should be for each row in given table. Also, when you mention 'None', how would you like to pass that to the stored procedure? *(The @Project variable is defined as integer)*

```
Parameter  Projects.ID  In Result
-----------------------------------------
1          1            Yes  
1          2            No  
1          NULL         No
'None'     1            No
'None'     2            No 
'None'     NULL         Yes
NULL       1            Yes
NULL       2            Yes
NULL       NULL         Yes
```

Comment: Your query has both `AND Projects.ID IS NULL` and `AND Projects.ID = ISNULL(@Project, Projects.ID)`. Aren't these contradictory?

Comment: Yes, I caught that too. I removed the "AND Projects.ID IS NULL". I was using that for testing.

Comment: The COALESCE approach unfortunately didn't change the results.

Comment: @Zogglet - I'm sure you are trying as best you can but the lack of answers clearly indicates to me that a lot of people have trouble with your requirements. I have added a trueth table to your answer. Perhaps if you complete it, it will clear things up.

Comment: I've filled out your truth table, and to answer your question regarding passing "None", I was referring to the implementation of this stored procedure as a dataset used in SSRS. I have added a "None" option to the available parameters, with a value of NULL. I have another "All" option, however, which passes =Nothing to the parameter, which successfully shows all records except for those with null values of ProjectID. This is the problem. Does that clear anything up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `LEFT JOIN` on `Products`, then you need to include that clause in `ON` not `WHERE`. Putting it in `WHERE` makes it an `INNER JOIN`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TasksByStatus]
  @Status  INT = NULL,
  @Project INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT 
    Task, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 101) AS StartDate, 
    (CASE WHEN CompleteDate IS NULL THEN 'Not complete yet' 
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CompleteDate, 101) END) AS CompleteDate, 
    (CASE WHEN Notes IS NULL THEN 'No notes provided' ELSE Notes END) AS Notes, 
    ProjectName, StatusName
  FROM dbo.Tasks 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Status ON Tasks.StatusID = Status.ID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Projects ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID 
  WHERE Status.ID = COALESCE(@Status, Status.ID) 
    AND COALESCE(Projects.ID, -1) = COALESCE(@Project, Projects.ID, -1)
  ORDER BY StartDate, StatusName;
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. That does in fact show those fields, but passing NULL to @Project also returns all other values, not just those with NULL ProjectID values. Is there a way to do this while still allowing for that parameter to be optional, as in, without a value passed to it versus NULL being passed to it?

Comment: You'll need to show sample data and desired results with and without a NULL parameter. I am having a hard time with the word problem, sorry.

Comment: With NULL parameter: return a record with Task, StartDate, CompleteDate, Notes, ProjectName and StatusName only if that record's ProjectID field is null. Without NULL parameter: Show all records with either the specified @Status parameter, or, if it isn't provided, show all records.

Comment: Try now please, assuming that `Projects.ID` is always positive. If this still doesn't yield the results you want, *PLEASE* add sample data and desired results to the question.

Comment: I apologize. How would you like me to provide sample data and results in the context of these comments?

Comment: Please add them to the question so everyone knows what data you have and what data you are expecting to get.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is the shortcut for disaster. Remember, SQL must compile a query plan that work for *any* value of the parameters. Therefore it will be pretty much forced to do a table scan on both `Status` and `Projects` tables *even when @Project and/or @Status were specified*! Erland Sommarskog covers this topic in detail at [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Separate this into 3 different queries:

```
if (@Status is null and @Project is null)
   select ...;
else if (@status is null)
   select ... where ProjectID = @Project;
else if (@project is null)
   select ... where StatusID = @status;
else
   select ... where StatusID = @status and ProjectID = @Project;
```

Comment: That is horrible, horrible code to maintain. If the size of the table becomes an issue I'd much rather circumvent the optimizer by using dynamic SQL and relying on ad hoc plans.

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, perhaps dynamic SQL is better than maintaining 4 forms of the query, although is arguable that maintaining the dynamic SQL *generating* code may be more difficult to troubleshoot. My main point it that this kind of jack-of-all-trades query is a disaster in the making. Ultimately the problem is in the application design that choose to create one API that apparently does 4 distinct tasks, instead of making 4 distinct APIs. This is just plain bad API design, but I gave up long ago in trying to address *that* on forums...